# Getting error while adding the new RestSharp update using nuGet.

Tags: asp.net, twilio

I am getting error in my windows service when I instantiate the TwilioRestClient.

It gives the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'RestSharp, Version=104.3.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I updated my references to the latest RestSharp, Twilio.Mvc and Twilio.Api from the Nuget and am getting the above error. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

I just pushed a new Nuget package with an updated reference to RestSharp.  I've also begun working on a new version that will remove the dependency on RestSharp to avoid this in the future.

Hope that helps.